# How to check remote Oracle server is up and running

Tags: oracle10g, remote-server

I have my Oracle server installed in a remote machine and I want a script at my local machine which will check whether Oracle server is up and running or not. I know this can be check by creating a connection through sqlplus or JDBC. But in this case oracle client won't be present  and I am saving JDBC approach as my last option. So is there any other simpler way to check this, which can be easily implemented in a shell script???

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The only way to be certain that the database is responding to queries is to run a query on it, such as the venerable:

```
select dummy from dual
```